# Как отправлять сообщение в лс пользователю?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Пишу бота тг на питоне библиотека telebot, хочу отправить сообщение в лс пользователю когда он в чат что-то напишет, как это сделать?

Comment: Ну, что проще то? Взять и сделать) А еще желательно почитать документацию своего API. Будет что-то непонятно, тогда и пишите

Comment: `bot.send_message(user_id, "text")`